# PHP custom superglobal Functions

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anyway to create custom superglobal functions in php?

I'm on shared server. and I want to change my timezone setting in MySQL.

I have added `SetEnv TZ America/Montreal` to .htaccess in my root folder, but it only has effect for PHP and won't affect MySQL `NOW()`, `CURDATE()`, `CURTIME()`. MySql still uses server's TimeZone.

Now I am thinking to create a superglobals PHP functions for example:

```
function now() { return date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); }
```

Is there anyway to make this function accessible for every single PHP file in my server without `include()` it on every single php files?

I am using many many scripts, like wordpress, phpbb, affiliate script, etc. and I dont want to change every single `now()` to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. It's not efficient to do this, or use `set time-zone` on every first MySQL connection.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use things like {PLEASE HELP} or other begging type phrasing in your questions. Your question is important to you, but this is a peer support site; others have questions they feel are important to them as well, and people here volunteer to help for free. If you need help so urgently you can't wait, you should hire someone who can give you their full attention to solve the problem instead. Adding noise to the question makes it harder for people to see what you're actually asking, and wastes the time of those who remove it instead of helping with answers.

Comment: Well, even if you would include that `now` function of yours into every file, you'd have to modify those scripts to use it. And wordpress uses it's own timezone setting anyway (See General Settings->Timezone in your wp-admin login). I'm certain that phpbb uses something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has an 'auto_prepend_file' option, which basically acts like an automatic "include()", but if you're on shared hosting, this is most likely NOT an option - it applies to all of PHP, which means everyone else you're sharing the server with will also get your code.

So basically, it boils down to "stop being lazy, and write out the `include()` in each file".

Comment: thank you very much. I add "php_value auto_prepend_file 'xxx.php'" in my root .htaccess so it only affect mine not everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going the wrong path. I would store the dates in GMT. Then on application level use whatever timezone you like. Why? What if your company moves somewhere else, or you have two offices in different timezones?. You need to be able to control this in one place and that's on the application level.

Take a look at https://code.sugarcrm.com/viewvc/public/trunk/sugarcrm/include/TimeDate.php?view=markup